# Inner product of a convolution with a test function

Tags: distribution-theory, fourier-transform, convolution

I am working through some class notes on Fourier transforms and convolutions.  Currently, we are trying to motivate the definition $\langle S * T, \phi \rangle := \langle S_x, \langle T_y, \phi(x+y) \rangle \rangle$, where $S$ and $T$ are distributions (not necessarily tempered).  The lecturer did it in this way: take $u,v \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that either $u$ or $v$ has compact support (this allows us to use Fubini-Tonelli later on).  Then
\begin{align*}
\langle u * v , \phi \rangle &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u(x-y) v(y) \phi(x) dy dx \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u(y) v(x) \phi(x+y) dx dy.
\end{align*}

Everything makes sense except the last line.  The use of Fubini-Tonelli is clear.  However, the inner portion confuses me.  It seems like we are using some sort of u-substitution, but this isn't enough.  Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the top line, make the substitutions $w:=y$ and $z:=x-y$.

Comment: That's the same as just making the substitution $z:= x-y$, though, which still leaves us with $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u(z) v(x-z) \phi(z+y) dz dy$.

Comment: Never mind, I see the trick!  Thank you!